# View Controller Containers

Tags: objective-c, containers

I'm currently implementing a child view within my view controller. Before implementing my child view my code would look for the navigation title and then decide what the output would be, which is what I have provide below (works fine). I have now implemented a container view and within the original view controller and I want that to look for the navigation title e.g. _TitleLabel but I'm not sure what I sure put on the container view controller.

```
self.navigationItem.title = _DetailModal[0];
_TitleLabel.text = _DetailModal [0];

if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Hello World"]) {
    ActualCode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@\r%@\r%@\r%@\r%@\r%@\r%@\r%@\r%@" ,
                 @"Public Class Form1",
                 @"",
                 @"Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click",
                 @"",
                 @"MsgBox(\"Hello World\")",
                 @"",
                 @"End Sub",
                 @"",
                 @"End Class"];
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide more context? I can't tell what method (or even class) the code in your question is part of, and it looks like most of the code in your snippet is unrelated to the problem. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Well orignally i have a simple table view array to a normal view controller. When clicking on a heading within the table view it displays its own specific view controller, in addition I would like to add a container view which then look at the tables headings to determine tthe content within the container. Just a recap I want my container view array to look up the title of the navigation bar of the previous view controller to determine the content. The code above work between the table view and the first view controller.

Comment: For starters, you seem to be going about things in a very backward way. You should *never* have to "look up the title of the navigation bar" because it's your own code that *sets* the title of the nav bar. You should already have the necessary information in your data model somewhere. Don't store data in views. Instead, set the content of views from your data.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to where I should correct my mistake, I believe I'm making more difficult for myself than it really is.  Could you give my guidance as at the moment I got from Table with cells which use a array which then populate a view controller (simple all working) I have now implemented a container view which I want to populate with certain information depending on the title from the main view controller but I don't know how to link. Any ideas, videos or example which I could learn from and implement.

Answer (score 0):

> I have now implemented a container view which I want to populate with certain information depending on the title from the main view controller

So think about what you're doing here. You're trying to use the view controller title to pass information to this container view. As I indicated in a comment, storing data in views is a bad idea. Where does the view controller title come from? What objects have access to that data?

Let's say that your UI consists of a table that lists various items, and a detail view that displays more information whenever the user taps a particular row in the table. It sounds like your container view is part of that detail display. So, when the user taps a row, the table view controller should figure out which row was tapped. It then grabs the item from the array that corresponds to the tapped row, and it should pass that item along to the detail view controller (usually in `-prepareForSegue:sender:`). The detail view controller takes that item and uses it to set its own title, probably in its `-viewWillAppear` method. At that point, it can also hand any necessary data (such as the title) to the container view.

Sometimes people summarize this approach with the phrase "tell, don't ask." That is, a view controller should provide any necessary data to the view, and a view should display whatever data it's given, but shouldn't fetch that data from anywhere.